# Python securely connect to MariaDB database

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to read the database of my MariaDB server. I have set it up like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE database1;
CREATE USER RaspberryPi@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* TO RaspberryPi@'%';
SELECT database1;
CREATE TABLE Users;
```

This is on my Raspberry Pi 4 with the IP: 192.168.0.92. Now I have This Python script on my Windows computer:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="192.168.0.92", user="RaspberryPi", passwd="password", database="database1")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
print(mycursor)
```

Now I convert my Python script to an .exe file using pyinstaller. My problem is, that if I give this file to some other people, he can easily convert the .exe file to his original .py file and then he has my login credentials. Can I code it somehow, that the username and password isn't shown or the script can't be converted back?

Thanks.

Comment: Normally you should be hosting an api. If the data is publicly accessible, you can just call the api. If the api should be protected too, then the user should be authenticating anyway.

Comment: @Pieterjan do you have a example where someone already did something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this snipet:

## Module Imports

```
import mariadb
import sys

# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="db_user",
        password="db_user_passwd",
        host="192.0.2.1",
        port=3306,
        database="employees"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get Cursor
cur = conn.cursor()
```

for more reference use this - https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/

Update:
in order to make it more secure you can put the username and password with get input

Comment: Well, this is something like the script I have but it doesn't solves my question. A person can still find the username and password from this code.

Comment: Thanks man, you have me an idea .